# How to add indexed:has taxonomy term id(with depth) in the contexual filter of view?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have created a view and added indexed fields to that view to show content.

I want to show content related to taxonomy "related place" as well as its related child taxonomy content. For selecting child taxonomy I used [simple hierarchical](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) module, but the problem I am facing is that I'm not getting any option to select Indexed:has taxonomy term id(with depth) in contexual filter to show content .

The propose of using indexed fields in views for filtering content using facet api.

I've tried everything to achieve this, but no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In custom module

- you can use hook__views_pre_view to change contextual filter,
- add children terms till depth to the contextual filter,
- function taxonomy_get_children_all() defined below, will fetch all child terms till depth:
- In view, don't forget to allow multiple value contextual filter for contextual filter.

  ```
  function taxonomy_get_children_all($tid, $vid = 0, $key = 'tid'){
    $c = taxonomy_get_children($tid, $vid, $key);
    $result = array();
    foreach ($c as $t => $d){
      $result[$t] = $d;
      $below = taxonomy_get_children_all($t, $vid, $key);
      if (!empty($below)) {
         foreach ($below as $nt => $nd){
           $result[$nt] = $nd;
         }
      }
   }
   return $result;
   }


   function formalter_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args){
   if($view->name == "category_view") { // && $display_id == "page") {
     $vid = <Your vocabulary id>;

     $t = $args[0];

     $tt = taxonomy_get_children_all($t,$vid);
     foreach($tt as $k => $v) {
       $a = (string)$k;
       $args[0] = $args[0] . "+" . $a;
     }
   }
  }
  ```